# Bootstrap Image can't set the width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please see [this site](http://find.netai.net/). There is an ad image below the navigation. I can't set it's width. I want to make it stretch and cover the blank white space. I've tried making it relative, absolute but so far the width remains the same. Please can anybody help me explain why this isn't working and what is it's solution. I think this is due to some grid system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS has

```
img {
max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

This effectively renders any other override useless. Please check `style1.css` line 420.

The width is governed by the parent (with `width:100%;` set). So you need to adjust your column utilities for Bootstrap to be wider or change the img class to be `width:100%;` rather than `max-width:100%`.

Realistically the problem lies in the form. It should be contained within a grid. The grid inside that should be 12 columns wide for the select menu (since that is also relative to the parent).

Rough example:

```
<div class="col-sm-5"><form>contents of form</form></div>
<div class="col-sm-7"><img src="advert.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your example. I would have done the same thing if I had written this code :)